# Singleton and different library versions

Tags: c++, singleton

I was building a library that is used in plugins for an application.
This library contains a singleton (I know singletons aren't liked here and I wouldn't have used one if there was a way around it).
Now, my question is:

What happens if two plugins were built with different versions of the library?

- Is this only a problem if the singleton class has changed?

  - Added methods / Removed methods / Changed signatures / Implementation changes
- Or is it always a problem?

**Edit**:
By plugins I'm referring to shared objects that are loaded at runtime. Basically, the application allows to export classes using a macro with known base classes and then after the library containing the plugin classes was loaded, the user can instantiate these plugins (the exported classes).
These base classes just define different types of plugins. I.e. plugins that affect interaction, visualization, etc.

Comment: Too many variables. Start narrowing down by describing what you mean by plug-in.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm trying to keep the question general but if the answer strongly depends on the context, I can go into the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library is static, there shouldn't be any problems because it's copyed in the plugin's code.

A dynamic library, however, is refered to from inside the program. If you use a plugin which used, let's say, v1.1 of your library and the application loading the plugin only knows version 1.0 you might get strange runtime behavior up to crashes.

The easiest way would be to implement some `getVersion()` function so the application can check if the assumed version is insstalled on the target system and fall back on earlier versions if that's not the case. It all depends on which functionality you use and if or how it was changed.

But to come back to your initial question: It doesn't matter if there are two plugins using different versions. It matters if one of these plugins uses an version not installled on the target.(dynamic libarary only)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I unfortunately can not modify the base application and in case I wasn't clear, the plugins all have to use the same singleton instance, so, it should be application-wide. I have already verified that that's the case if the version is equal. I  assume that the first plugin that gets loaded, creates its version of the singleton, right?
If so, would subsequent plugins that were built with a newer version create a new instance of their version of the singleton or would they access the old version using the contract defined in the header of the newer version?

Comment: If you just make the main program create the singleton by calling it you call code who does not know about the new version. However, if your plugin compiles the whole singleton-code itself it's likely the instance is created from that code and therefore is the new version. But i recommend to just use the old version because either the main program or the plugin could get confused if a memory object isn't aligned as it should be for them.

Comment: I think calling it application-wide was a bit misleading. The main program doesn't even know about the singleton. It is included in the plugins and only used by them. But if I understand you correctly, the singleton would only be created by the first plugin that accesses it and use the version of that plugin and plugins with other versions would access the memory object using their version? Could I get around this by using a singleton to manage a *worker class* that does all the work and whenever a plugin is loaded it checks the version of the *worker class* and if it's older it replaces it?

Comment: This way the singleton would only forward calls and the implementation could change, right? Of course, the signatures would have to stay the same so only the implementation could change.

Comment: If only the plugins use the singleton and they don't know anything of each other you probably won't have any problems at all because every plugin has it's own singleton. They don't know that there might be another class using the same code and just create everything anew.

Comment: They are using the same singleton. I've done some experiments and interestingly, there wasn't even an issue when I changed the signature of the getSingleton to also require a boolean parameter. I assume that was because the singleton is only accessed directly from within the library and the plugins only inherit from the class that interacts with the singleton. If I also used the singleton in the plugin classes directly (and changed signature), it seemed like it created two instances of the singleton (I logged the creation). However, it behaved as if there was only one which is really weird.

Comment: You could change the return value of one of the functions of your singleton to a fixed value, call it and see what return value you get. If you get that fixed value you are using a  new instance, if not, you are not.

Comment: It also yould be possible that your singleton uses static member variables so even if you create a new instance of the same class they both may behave as if they were one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159482/discussion-between-stefan-fabian-and-detonar).